# Android: Start the circular progress bar from top (270°)

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-progressbar

I have defined a circular progress bar using the following drawable `"ciruclar_progress_bar.xml"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="25.0" >
        <gradient
            android:centerColor="@color/gray"
            android:endColor="@color/gray"
            android:startColor="@color/gray"
            android:type="sweep" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="25.0" >
        <gradient
            android:centerColor="@color/green"
            android:endColor="@color/green"
            android:startColor="@color/green"
            android:type="sweep" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

and I have used this drawable for `ProgressBar` in my layout using the following code

```
  <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressWheel"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="152dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:progress="100"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />
```

I used following code to show progress on the `ProgressBar`

```
progressWheel.setSecondaryProgress(percent);
```

(Used secondary progress because the green color should come on top of the black color of the ring.)

This draws the circular `ProgressBar` whose starting position is on the right (0°) as shown in the following image

[image]

I want the progress to start from the top as shown in the following image

[image]

I tried putting `android:angle="270"` in the gradient tag of drawable xml but had no luck. Is there any way I can start the sweep angle from the top?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try specifying rotation degrees to your progress items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:toDegrees="270"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%" >
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="25.0" >
                <gradient
                    android:centerColor="@color/gray"
                    android:endColor="@color/gray"
                    android:startColor="@color/gray"
                    android:type="sweep" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:toDegrees="270"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%" >
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="25.0" >
                <gradient
                    android:centerColor="@color/green"
                    android:endColor="@color/green"
                    android:startColor="@color/green"
                    android:type="sweep" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thanks. After some experiments, I found that I needed fromDegress and toDegrees set to 270 so that it does not rotate and starts from top.

Comment: You can just set rotation to secondaryProgress item, no need for the first one. But thanks anyway, I've been struggling with this.

Comment: can I set a starting angle in a ProgressBar?

Answer (score 35):

You can also apply a rotation to your ProgressBar in layout XML. In your case -90° would solve your problem.

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressDemo"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="152dp"
        android:layout_height="152dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progress="10"
        android:rotation="-90"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's how I made circular progressbar with percentage inside circle in pure code without any library.

Reference is taken from here : [circular progress bar android](https://demonuts.com/circular-progress-bar/)

[image]

first create a drawable file called `circular.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="6"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
            android:useLevel="true">


            <gradient
                android:centerColor="#999999"
                android:endColor="#999999"
                android:startColor="#999999"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="270"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="270">

            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="6"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
                android:useLevel="true">


                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="0"
                    android:pivotX="50%"
                    android:pivotY="50%"
                    android:toDegrees="360" />

                <gradient
                    android:centerColor="#00FF00"
                    android:endColor="#00FF00"
                    android:startColor="#00FF00"
                    android:type="sweep" />

            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Now in your `activity_main.xml`  add following:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dialog"
    tools:context="com.example.parsaniahardik.progressanimation.MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar

        android:id="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular"
        android:secondaryProgress="100"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@drawable/whitecircle"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="25%"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In `activity_main.xml` I have used one circular image with white background to show white background around percentage. Here is the image:

[image]

You can change color of this image to set custom color around percentage text.

Now finally add following code to `MainActivity.java` :

```
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.animation.DecelerateInterpolator;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int pStatus = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Resources res = getResources();
        Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.circular);
        final ProgressBar mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.circularProgressbar);
        mProgress.setProgress(0);   // Main Progress
        mProgress.setSecondaryProgress(100); // Secondary Progress
        mProgress.setMax(100); // Maximum Progress
        mProgress.setProgressDrawable(drawable);

      /*  ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mProgress, "progress", 0, 100);
        animation.setDuration(50000);
        animation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        animation.start();*/

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (pStatus < 100) {
                    pStatus += 1;

                    handler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            mProgress.setProgress(pStatus);
                            tv.setText(pStatus + "%");

                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        // Sleep for 200 milliseconds.
                        // Just to display the progress slowly
                        Thread.sleep(8); //thread will take approx 1.5 seconds to finish
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

If you want to make horizontal progressbar, follow this link, it has many valuable examples with source code:
http://www.skholingua.com/android-basic/user-interface/form-widgets/progressbar

Comment: Dude, why do you even need that white image? Didn't the accepted answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @Zeba I got my answer. For people having the same problem here is the updated `circular_progress_bar.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="25.0" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="120"
                android:centerColor="@color/gray"
                android:endColor="@color/gray"
                android:startColor="@color/gray"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="270"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="270" >
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="2.5"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thicknessRatio="25.0" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="120"
                android:centerColor="@color/green"
                android:endColor="@color/green"
                android:startColor="@color/green"
                android:type="sweep" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Comment: Using the exact same tutorial. How have you gotten around the issue of  having the whole thing collapse when you set the secondary progress to 100% / whatever the max value is?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? I don't see any issue even if the progress or secondary progress reaches 100%. The max for me is 100 only.

Comment: Annoyingly, this turned out to be a bug in Android Studio rather than an issue with the code.

Answer (score 1):

A more simple solution I found is rotating the view 270 degrees, setting the inner text to transparent and setting new TextView on top of the  circular progress bar with your data-

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
        android:id="@+id/donut_progress_lodging"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        app:donut_text_color="@color/tw__transparent"
        android:rotation="270"
        app:donut_finished_color="#34c6f1"
        app:donut_finished_stroke_width="5dp"
        app:donut_unfinished_color="#276894"
        app:donut_unfinished_stroke_width="5dp" />

  <TextView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0%"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView_percentage_lodging"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for rotating any view by some angle is giving rotation in XML.

```
<ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
      style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:max="100"
      android:progress="0"
      android:rotation="-90"
      android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular" />
```